# Azure Data Factory - Error Code 11402 - value of property invalid

Tags: azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, dataverse

I just stumbled upon an error regarding the linked services (under connections) of my Data Factory. Today I just wanted to create a new connection to a Dynamics CRM System, but encountered the following error code:

*Error code 11402
DetailsThe value of the property 'Organization Name' is invalid: 'Organization cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: Organization Name'.
Organization cannot be null or empty.
Parameter name: Organization Name
Activity ID: ccdf3a23-f43a-4256-8ecc-af46ca17638d.*

For some reason this even occurs if I duplicate an existing Dataverse-connection. Now all my connections won't work anymore and I wonder if I screwed up some configuration by accident. Unfortunately I can't seem to find an option to enter the Organization Name nor does a Parameter with such a name exist (e. g. in a Dataset).

Has anyone a hint where I can enter the Organization Name or can bypass this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: most probably your url is incorrect or has issues with semicolon or so on. Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-troubleshoot-dynamics-dataverse) and search for organization. In addition take a look at [this post](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/error-Organization-cannot-be-null-or-empty-Parameter-name/td-p/606650) as well it will help.

Comment: Could you please help me with the below details because with the given information it is difficult the find the exact issue. 1. Which connector you are using, Dynamic 365 or Dynamic CRM? 2. In which step you are getting the error, `Test Connection` or when creating the Linked Service? 3. Please share some snippet of what have you tried. 

From the error message, I can just interpret that the organization name in the Service URI isn't correct. The URI must be in this format`https://<organization-name.crm[x].dynamics.com>`. If the given URI isn't in this format, please check again.

Comment: The URL was entered correctly.In fact, the connection failed like after a week or so.But I guess someone else in the organization changed a parameter or s. th.
Now I can connect with the proper URL,when I use the same credentials (URL,user name,password),but using a Dynamics CRM connection instead of a Dataverse connection.I also had to switch from an office 365 to a service princial connection type.
When the connection failed,the error occured both on creating the linked service as well as the test connection.The URL was also in the format that Utkarsh Pal stated.
So thank you both still!